# Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined Error in React when adding Social sign-in (OAuth) with AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm working with ReactJs and trying to add Social sign-in using AWS Amplify, i follow all the steps (provide the redirect signin/signout URI, Google Web Client ID and secret for my OAuth) and then this error shows.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
at userPoolDefaults (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-category-auth\src\provider-utils\awscloudformation\assets\cognito-defaults.js:24:47)
at Object.identityAndUserPoolDefaults [as identityPoolAndUserPool] (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-category-auth\src\provider-utils\awscloudformation\assets\cognito-defaults.js:66:6)
at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-category-auth\src\provider-utils\awscloudformation\utils\auth-defaults-appliers.ts:46:54
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-category-auth\src\provider-utils\awscloudformation\handlers\resource-handlers.ts:39:31
at Object.executeAmplifyCommand (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-category-auth\src\index.js:379:3)
at executePluginModuleCommand (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\src\execution-manager.ts:175:3)
at Object.executeCommand (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\src\execution-manager.ts:28:5)
at Object.run (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\src\index.ts:146:5)
```

There was an error adding the auth resource

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error occurred because I moved the entire repo folder to another place, I corrected it by returning the folder to where it had it.

I discovered it because I tried to `amplify pull` to see if it would be corrected, and I got an error that it could not find `team-provider-info.json`, being that if it was there, until I notice that the path where I was looking for it was where it had before file